# Drag image with combobox below

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

How can I dragg an image with combobox below using jquery draggable.

I don't know if I need to create a Div and inside put the image and combobox.

I already have the image draggable, but I'm not sure how can I put the combobox below.

Comment: Need to see some code before we can help diagnose the problem you are having or guide you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without any code listed, but here is the setup from the draggable docs:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

It seems as though you would need the box below the element with id "draggable". You can set the box to be droppable the same way you use $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

But again, a code sample would be very helpful.